# How to play mp4 video in offline html5 based Android app using webview?

Tags: android, html, video, webview, mp4

I am building an Android app that should work off-line displaying several html pages that each might contain one or two small embedded mp4 videos. The original html files were used to build the iPhone app that runs without any problem. When the user navigates to a new page, the video files should start playing  without any user interaction. The small embedded videos should automatically start and loop infinitely. I use Android Studio 1.3.2 on Linux Mint 17.2 and with trial and error, and carefully trying some suggestions I found here, I managed to build an app (Android 4.4.2) as follows:

In the AndroidManifest.xml I have added hardware acceleration and given access to internet:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The app is build using:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 22
```

In MainActivity.java I have added WebChromeClient and enabled JavaScript. I prevent the user from having to initially touch before a video can be autoplayed using the setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture option:

```
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

In the index.html file I have the following few attempts to embed a movie file. The movie is the same mp4 file in all three cases that I copied to the different folders:

```
<body>
1) Intern mp4, resides in assets/www
  <video id="vid2" width="100%" autoplay loop controls>
    <source src="./mov_bbb.mp4">
  </video>

2) extern SDcard
  <video id="video" width="100%" autoplay loop controls>
     <source src="file:///mnt/sdcard/cmr/mov_bbb.mp4">
  </video>

3) online WWW
  <video id="video" width="100%" autoplay loop controls>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
  </video>
</body>
```

1)Trying to load and play a mp4 located in assets/www (same as where index.html is located) and packed inside package does not work. When I press play button, the video box turns black and resizes to the size of the video, but it doesn't play, I got unknown error:

```
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (1001, 0)
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)
```

2)Video starts automatically but does not loop. Besides, I don want to have all the movie files located in the external SD card:

```
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (3, 0)
```

3)Online content: Video starts automatically but does not loop. I don't want the app to depend on network. Off-line access is an essential part of app.

```
I/MediaPlayer﹕ setDataSource(http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4)
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (3, 0)
```

Is there any reason why embedding mp4 video in package just as you can do with images and html files does not work? Is there a workaround using additional scripting perhaps that might solve my challenge in building the app? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you change locate save video to sdcard